# Using Python subprocess to keep track of files created by the executable

Tags: python

I am new to python and to Redhat linux. I am using the subprocess module to execute another C program that creates a file. I am able to capture the exit code from the C program. But is there any way I can also make python track and display the name of the file created by the C program?

Note: I cannot modify the C program. The C program creates output files with timestamps and many instances of it could be running in parallel. I only want to capture the files created by the instance run by python.
Is there any other way to do this if not the subprocess module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided you can get the process ID of the C program.  You can do that with the `pid` attribute of the object returned from `subprocess.Popen`.

Having got the pid you can open the process's entry in the `/proc` filesystem, and look in the `fd` subdirectory.  This contains symbolic links to all the files that the process has open.  Those links can be followed to get the real filename.

For example, this returns a list of the filenames:

```
import re
import os

def get_filenames(pid):

    dir = '/proc/' + str(pid) + '/fd'
    if not os.access(dir, os.R_OK|os.X_OK): return
    filenames = []

    for fds in os.listdir(dir):
        for fd in fds:
            full_name = os.path.join(dir, fd)
            try:
                 filename = os.readlink(full_name)
                 if filename == '/dev/null' or \
                   re.match(r'pipe:\[\d+\]',file) or \
                   re.match(r'socket:\[\d+\]',file):
                      filename = None
            except OSError as err:
                if err.errno == 2:     
                    filename = None
                else:
                    raise(err)

            if filename:
                filenames.append(filename)  

    return filenames
```

Alternatively, download `psutil` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil and use the `get_open_files()` method.

Note that, whichever mechanism you use, there is the possibility of a race condition because usually you do not know when the C program opens or closes the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the os.listdir cannot find the directory corresponding to the fid. Is it because the c program could be closing the file before python script can look for it?

Comment: @user1802785   More likely the process has ended.  The fd directory should be there even if there are no files open, although fd's 0, 1, 2 are usually there (stdin, stdout, stderr).  Note this will only work on Linux, other Unix's don't have the symbolic links (OS X doesn't have /proc)